# WPF: Unable to find the requested .Net framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: wpf, clickonce

Edit this question upon getting more exception details.

I have a WPF application that is crashing on one particular installation of Windows XP.

I have managed to get the exception details, and the culprit seems to be:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

A little info about the project:
It uses .net 4, sql server compact and version 2.1 of the sync framework. The error, I think, is related to the entity framework connecting to the sql server compact database.

On windows 7 this installs and runs fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the TargetFrameworkVersion and ToolsVersion in project file to 4.0

also check [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/feedback/viewfeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=260910&wa=wsignin1.0&siteid=210)

Comment: The target is already .net 4, thats how I switched it - not sure what ToolsVersion is.